# При работе в команде, как правильно подтягивать изменения из веток в git?

Tags: git

Во время работы в команде над одним продуктом возник вопрос - как правильно и корректно подтягивать изменения других коллег с их веток или с ветки dev (основной, скажем так).

Когда я работаешь один, таких вопросов естественно не возникает и мне между двумя моими машинами было достаточно `git pull` - подтянуть изменения свои на одной машине - продолжить работать на другой и снова закомитить.

Так как все таки правильно? Я вижу три решения:

1) `git pull` - подтягиваем все изменения и работаем уже с изененными файлами
из минусов вижу только то что все изменения отображаются как "мои"

2) `git merge` - мержить свою ветку с чужими и работать дальше

3) `git cherry-pick` - вносить в свою ветку коммиты коллег, которые в ветке будут отображаться как "мои"
из минусов вижу только долгий и не удобный перебор всех хешей коммитов

Так вот вопрос - как все таки правльно подтягивать изменения из веток других людей?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос субъективный. Когда вам нужно опубликовать код из своей ветки в основную, у вас есть по сути четыере опции:

- просто merge вашей ветки в основную;
- rebase вашей ветки на head основной (линеаризация истории);
- комбирированный вариант rebase + merge;
- перенос патчей (cherry-pick).

Все они имеют плюсы и минусы. Выбирают, то что подходит к текущему проекту/нравится команде. Кроме того, они могут использоваться совместно в рамках сложного workflow.

Сами по себе git flow, github flow, gitlab flow и прочие flow не являются серебрянной пулей и на маленьких проектах в небольшой команде могут доставлять больше сложностей, чем удобств.

Answer (score 7):

Давно придумали [git-flow](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/), которое решает все вопросы. Даже есть [шпаргалка](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html).

`git pull` на самом деле по умолчанию делает `git fetch` + `git merge`, поэтому второй  вариант включает как бы первый. `git pull` умеет ещё ребейзить, но этим пользуются те, кто понимает. И если отбросить мишуру, то ребейз формально делает серию `git cherry-pick`.

Подсумируем. Как правильно. Когда нужно сделать фичу, делаем ветку от девелопа (или мастера), делаем фичу. Если фича делается долго - поливаем изменения с ветки себе (`git checkout develop && git pull && git checkout - && git merge develop`) - этим упростим мердж в будущем. Когда фича готова - мержим назад в девелом (мастер). Можно напрямую, можно через pull/merge request.

Comment: спасибо за статью - ознакомлюсь. А про эту настройку где то слышал, надо будет поковыряться с ней - может даже подойдет)

Comment: Прикольно, но частный случай.

Comment: Что именно? Git flow?