# Работа в команде c GIT

Tags: git, github

Идет разработка проекта, добавляются новые люди в команду. Контроль версиями осуществляется с помощью GIT. Разъяснить алгоритм подключения нового человека к работе над проектом. Допустим последний коммит имеет название second.

1. Создается новая ветка для нового разработчика
2. Он клонирует репозиторий проекта
3. Переходит в свою ветку

Вопрос 1: Я правильно понимаю алгоритм добавления нового разработчика к проекту?

Вопрос 2: После клонирования новый разработчик начинает свою работу, в своей ветке, с коммита second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно создавать под разработчика специально ветку. Это контрпродуктивно.

Ветки создают разработчики под фичи (задачи/баги). Нормально, когда есть несколько долгоживущих веток (master/develop) и много краткоживущих под задачи.

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/
- http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html

а также здесь  на сайте:)

- [При работе в команде, как правильно подтягивать изменения из веток в git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608359/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-git)

Comment: Но возможен и такой вариант: https://gitlab.i-free.com/m.ivanov/gitmem/wikis/home (начинается с того, что у каждого разработчика есть свой клон мастера)

Comment: Учитывая, что каждый разработчик клонирует себе репозиторий, у каждого и так будет "свой мастер":)

Comment: @KoVadim, под одной веткой работают несколько разработчиков для решения одной задачи? так?

Comment: Нет, это не клон в смысле полученный при помощи `git clone`, а именно свой форк мастер-ветки на удалённом сервере, которая для этого разработчика и считается мастером/апстримом. В основной мастер что-то попадает только после пуша в свою копию мастера и принятия мерж-реквеста из неё.

Comment: @bsart2017 обычно над одной задачей работает один разработчик. И он себе под это дело создает ветку. Когда работа завершена - мержит в мастер/девелом.

Comment: @PinkTux Это же классический pull request! На любителя.

Comment: @KoVadim Иногда можно воспользоваться `git worktree` если задача "на один комит" (Шерлок-программист).